# TranslateAnimation from outside to inside the screen is clipped

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to "slide in" two views from the bottom and the top of a `ListView`.

My list has a "featured" item. When this featured item is scrolled down the visible part of the `ListView`, a button appears at the bottom to scroll to the featured item position, and, similarly, when it's scrolled up the visible part of the `ListView`, a button appears at the top.

The issue is that the part of the buttons that are outside the screen before the "slide in" animation is clipped at the end of the animation. I tried to set `android:clipChildren="false"` on all the parent views but it's still clipped.

How can I achieve that?

**Featured item is in yellow**

[image]

**If the featured item is scrolled beyond the top of the screen the top button appears, but it's clipped (only the part corresponding to the size of the header is shown)**

[image]

**If the featured item is scrolled beyond the bottom of the screen the bottom button appears, but it's clipped (only the part corresponding to the size of the footer is shown)**

[image]

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_test.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    public TestFragment() {}

    private ListView listView;

    private int featuredItemPosition = 10;

    /* Scroll buttons */

    private TextView scrollUpBtn, scrollDownBtn;

    private enum FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS {
        UP,
        DOWN,
        VISIBLE
    }
    private FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS featuredItemRelativePos;

    TranslateAnimation hideScrollDownBtnAnim, showScrollDownBtnAnim,
            showScrollUpBtnAnim, hideScrollUpBtnAnim;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

        scrollUpBtn = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll_up_btn);
        scrollDownBtn = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.scroll_down_btn);

        // Create animation
        float density = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        showScrollDownBtnAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 50 * density);
        hideScrollDownBtnAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 50 * density, 0);
        showScrollUpBtnAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -50 * density);
        hideScrollUpBtnAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -50 * density, 0);

        showScrollDownBtnAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        hideScrollDownBtnAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        hideScrollUpBtnAnim.setFillAfter(true);
        showScrollUpBtnAnim.setFillAfter(true);

        showScrollDownBtnAnim.setDuration(500);
        hideScrollDownBtnAnim.setDuration(500);
        hideScrollUpBtnAnim.setDuration(500);
        showScrollUpBtnAnim.setDuration(500);

        listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<20; i++) items.add("row " + i);
        String[] array = new String[items.size()];

        listView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getActivity(), items.toArray(array)));

        // Scroll to current match
        listView.setSelection(featuredItemPosition);
        featuredItemRelativePos = FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.VISIBLE;

        listView.setOnScrollListener(onScrollListener);

    }

    class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private Context context;

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
        }

        public TestAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
            super(context, 0, items);
            layoutInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {
                v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_row, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText(getItem(position));
            if(position==featuredItemPosition) holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            else holder.text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            return v;
        }
    }

    private AbsListView.OnScrollListener onScrollListener =
            new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


                    if(featuredItemRelativePos==FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.VISIBLE &&
                            firstVisibleItem > featuredItemPosition){
                        featuredItemRelativePos = FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.UP;
                        scrollDownBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        scrollDownBtn.startAnimation(showScrollDownBtnAnim);
                        Log.d("TestFragment", "Show scroll btn at top");
                    }
                    else if (featuredItemRelativePos==FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.UP &&
                            firstVisibleItem <= featuredItemPosition){
                        featuredItemRelativePos = FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.VISIBLE;
                        scrollDownBtn.startAnimation(hideScrollDownBtnAnim);
                        Log.d("TestFragment", "Hide scroll btn at top");
                    }
                    else if(featuredItemRelativePos==FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.VISIBLE &&
                            firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount -1 < featuredItemPosition){
                        featuredItemRelativePos = FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.DOWN;
                        scrollUpBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        scrollUpBtn.startAnimation(showScrollUpBtnAnim);
                        Log.d("TestFragment", "Show scroll btn at bottom");
                    }
                    else if (featuredItemRelativePos==FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.DOWN &&
                            firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount -1 >= featuredItemPosition){
                        featuredItemRelativePos = FEATURED_ITEM_RELATIVE_POS.VISIBLE;
                        scrollUpBtn.startAnimation(hideScrollUpBtnAnim);
                        Log.d("TestFragment", "Hide scroll btn at bottom");
                    }
                }
            };
}
```

**fragment_test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/scroll_down_btn"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/listview"
        android:text="scroll_down_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#987987"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/scroll_up_btn"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/listview"
        android:text="scroll_up_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#987987"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#646464"
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#646464"
        android:text="FOOTER"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**test_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```